# 7zip command line: how to exclude subfolders only but include files?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

Assume we have a folder structure like this:

```
Basefolder
|--data
   |--system1
   |--personal
   |--testing
|--doc
|--photo
```

and assume there are files under every subfolders.

When creating a 7z archive of "Basefolder" by 7zip command line options, is it possible to exclude all subfolders under "data", but include all files directly inside "data"? The folder name "data" is known and will never change. But it's unknown how many subfolders are under it and what the subfolder names are.